# Can a build template be based on another build template on TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity 9.0.2, and I would like to make a template implement another template, or make a build configuration implement more than one template.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible but already requested for a long time in [TW-12153](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-12153) (maybe you would like to vote for it).

To share several build steps among several build configurations or build configuration templates, I am using [meta runners](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Working+with+Meta-Runner):

> A Meta-Runner allows you to extract build steps, requirements and parameters from a build configuration and create a build runner out of them.
> This build runner can then be used as any other build runner in a build step of any other build configuration or template.

Although using meta runners works as a workaround for us, editing meta runners is not as convenient as editing a build configuration template (as it usually requires editing the meta runner definition XML file by hand).

### Update 2021

As @zosal points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077907/1811525) TeamCity meanwhile provides another way of sharing common build configuration data or logic by means of the [Kotlin DSL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/kotlin-dsl.html). The Kotlin DSL is a very powerful tool but may not always fit in your specific scenario. I would recommend to at least give it a try or watch [one of the introductory tutorial videos](https://youtu.be/AEYjAnR2-MY).

Answer (score 8):

This was not available when you asked the question but since Team City 10 you can now use [Kotlin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Kotlin+DSL) to configure your builds and thus your templates.

From this you can make Templates implement other Templates.

I myself have made Templates inherit from other templates to cut down on reconfiguration time and to not have to repeat myself so many times.

```java
open class TheBaseTemplate(uuidIn: String, extIdIn: String, nameIn: String, additionalSettings: Template.() -> Unit) : Template({
    uuid = uuidIn
    extId = extIdIn
    name = nameIn
    /* all the other settings that are the same for the derived templates*/
    additionalSettings()
})

object DerivedTemplateA : TheBaseTemplate("myUuidA", "myExtIdA", "myNameA", {
    params {
        param("set this", "to this")
    }
})

object DerivedTemplateB : TheBaseTemplate("myUuidB", "myExtIdB", "myNameB", {
    params {
        param("set this", "to that")
    }
})

object Project : Project({
    uuid = "project uuid"
    extId = "project extid"
    name = "project name"

    buildType {
        template(DerivedTemplateA)
        /* the uuid, extId and name are set here */
    }

    buildType {
        template(DerivedTemplateB)
        /* the uuid, extId and name are set here */
    }

    template(DerivedTemplateA)
    template(DerivedTemplateB)
})
```

The above code might be very hard to understand. It ***will*** take some time to familiarise yourself with Kotlin, what it does, and how it interfaces with TeamCity. I should point out that some imports are missing.

Additionally, take the example with a pinch of salt. It is a quick example to demonstrate one way of templates implementing other templates. Do not take this example as the definitive way to do things.